# Initializing state on opening new window

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, asynchronous

So lets say that I already have jwt token in cookies and in my state i store status LoggedIn: true/false. I would like to be logged in when I open new tab with the same vue site. Here is my store classes:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";
import { auth } from "./auth.module";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      storage: window.sessionStorage,
    }),
  ],
  modules: {
    auth,
  },
});
```

and in auth store

```
import AuthService from "../services/auth.service";
import axios from "axios";
const API_URL = process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_API + "/users/";

const user = axios.get(API_URL + "roles", { withCredentials: true }).then( <-- RETURNING PROMISE
  (user) => {
    console.log("login: ", user.data);
    return user.data;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
);

const initialState = user
  ? { status: { loggedIn: true }, user }
  : { status: { loggedIn: false }, user: null };

export const auth = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState,
  actions: {
    login({ commit }, user) { .......
................
................
```

I would like to initialize user at start with data from api, but I'm always catching promise. Program doesn't wait for response. The function in backend is async.

Answer (score 0):

why not just put your auth function(axios) in vuex action block and call it when at starting stage?

```js
const fetch = () => axios.get(API_URL + "roles", { withCredentials: true }).then( <-- RETURNING PROMISE
  (user) => {
    console.log("login: ", user.data);
    return user.data;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
);

function initialState (user) {
  return user ? { status: { loggedIn: true }, user }
  : { status: { loggedIn: false }, user: null };
}

export const auth = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState(),
  mutations: {
    SET_STATE (user) {
      initialState(user)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async init ({ commit }) {
      const data = await fetch()
      commit('SET_STATE', data)
    },
    login({ commit }, user) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. There's no error in your code, but the problem is that now user isn't initiated. There's no console.log, nor user in state "user : null". Should I envoke method init somewhere?

Comment: How method init would know that it needs to start at opening new tab or refrershing the page? I'm new to Vuex, thats why I'm asking.

Comment: you cant just call it in your app.vue in `mounted` or `created`

Comment: `mounted () {
  this.$store.dispatch('init')
}`

Comment: aw, do not forget you have namespace. `dispatch('your_namespace/init')`

Comment: Oh nice, Thanks for your help, will try and then tell you if it works.